# How to push a character into a new line?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to create a code where I would get a user input, take that into a loop and it would display a triangle.

```
    ;; using a nested loop create a triangle
section .data
        global _start
        prompt db "Enter number of lines you'd like: ",10 ;;declare constant string that  points to ’string’ 10 equates to the line character
        promptLen equ $-prompt ;; This returns the length of the string
        char db ' ' ; declare char to store asterisks and newlines
segment .bss
    num1 resb 1
section .text
_start:
        mov eax,4 ;; Move the system call 4 to the register eax to say ouput
        mov ebx,1 ;;  put the value 1 in the register ebx - standard output to the screen
        mov ecx, prompt ; Put the offset of string in ecx register so we can access the string and the new line character
        mov edx, promptLen ;; put the length of the string into the register
        int 80h ; Call the operating system with an interrupt. The operating system checks the registers and performs the operation to write to screen
        mov eax,3 ; system call input
        mov ebx, 0 ; stand input
        mov ecx, num1 ; store inputted value in num1 - note ascii value and should be between 1-9
        mov edx, 1 ; size of input value in bytes
        int 80h ; call kernel with interrupt to receive value
        mov rax, [num1] ; move value in num1 into rax
        sub rax, 48; subtract 48 from value so now it is integer and not ascii value
        mov [num1], rax ; move value back into num1 use ax for the row counter
        mov rax, [num1]; move num1 into rax to set the size of the outer loop - rows of triangle
        outer_loop: ; use ax for the row counter
                mov rbx, [num1] ; move num1 into rbx to set the size of the inner loop
                inner_loop: ;; draw a asterisk
                        call asterisk ;; subtract from the counter and repeat if we haven't hit 0 for inner loop
                        dec bx
                        cmp bx,0
                        jg inner_loop ;; go on to next line
                call linefeed ; subtract from the counter and repeat if we haven't hit 0 for outer loop
                dec ax
                cmp ax,0
                jne outer_loop  ;; go to next line
                call linefeed ;; exit cleanly

exit:
        mov eax,1; system call to exit
        mov ebx,0; exit value
        int 80h; call kernel with interrupt to exit program
        ret;; new line code section

linefeed:
        ;; move newline character into char
        mov [char],  byte 10
        push rax; push rax on to stack to allow outer loop to 
                ; occur
        push rbx; push rbx on to stack to allow inner loop to 
            ; occur
        mov eax,4; system call to write out
        mov ebx,1; standard out to screen
        mov ecx, char; go to next line on screen
        mov edx,1; size of new line
        int 80h; interrupt to kernel to go to next line by 
            ; looking into registers
        pop rbx; push rax on to stack to allow outer loop to 
            ; occur
        pop rax; push rbx on to stack to allow inner loop to 
            ; occur
        ret

asterisk:

        mov [char],  byte '*'; put asterisk (*) in char
        push rax; push rax on to stack to allow outer loop to occur
        push rbx; push rbx on to stack to allow inner loop to occur
        mov eax,4; system call to write out
        mov ebx,1; standard out to screen
        mov ecx, char; put asterisk in register ecx
        mov edx,1; size of asterisk in register
        int 80h; interrupt to kernel to print asterisk on screen by looking into registers
        pop rbx
        pop rax

        ret
```

Yes, I know it's unclean but I'm trying to learn how to add character to new line.

The end result should look more like this.

- (1 asterisk)

** (Push asterisk in new line)

*** (Push asterisk in another new line and then so on)

How can I do this in a loop and with the push commands?

Comment: what is wrong with your current code? (except you are mixing 64b with 32b syscalls, which is not recommended, rather pick one and use only that, but otherwise we don't have crystal ball, where it fails, from a 5 second glimpse over it it looks that it actually even may do something reasonably close to your intention, if there are no bugs)

Comment: Although I see one problem, which you may even miss, if you "test" it by running it and the OS is merciful in allocating memory for your process.... what is `mov rax, [num1]` doing, exactly? And how did you manipulate memory at `num1` address ahead of it? There is a discrepancy between these two.

Comment: At the moment, it is causing a 3 by 3 like a square rather than in a triangle scheme. For example, if given input 3, it would comes out with 3 asterisks per line. I'm trying to make an incremental like 1st line would be 1 asterisk. 2nd line -- 2 asterisks, 3rd line would be 3 asterisks.

Comment: ok, so you are really lucky... to see the first problem, move `num1` to `.data` and allocate it as `num1: db 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` (should basically do the same thing, right? The additional bytes shouldn't affect it) and then watch in debugger, what is actually loaded into `rax`. (don't try to run it, you will probably not see much). About looping from 1 to input number... yeah, so do it.. maybe cut down a bit register usage, so you have more spare registers, although you still have some, especially in 64b mode) .. then you can have all the counters and test values in registers (mem is slow)

Comment: That didn't work. It looped on the asterisk to a ridiculous amount until it terminated on its own. Maybe it has to do with the loop within the inner_loop.

Comment: I asked you what exactly does `mov rax, [num1]` ... can you describe, what the instruction does?

Comment: It's supposed to be an editable memory where the user can give a number. It's to define how many loop for the rows of the triangle.

Comment: that's the high-level description of what you want, but I'm asking about the machine instruction, what exactly it does (in every code it does what is defined in the instruction guide, it's not aware of your wish). Try to describe that low level part.

Comment: And the answer was, that it loads 8 bytes from address `num1` into `rax`. But user did enter only 1 byte. So the upper 56 bits of `rax` were some random memory content, in my 0, 1, 2, ... example the `rax` would be loaded as (with user inputting `'4'`): `0x0706050403020134` ... after subtracting 48 it's still asking for pyramid of size about 2**58, which would not fit on monitor even with 4k resolution... That's why my code does load only single `byte`, and does use `movzx` to extend that byte with zero bits up to full 32b value.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I would resolve such task by this:

```
    ; NOT using a nested loop create a triangle
    ; rather using line buffer to buffer the I/O operations to make it faster
section .data
        prompt db "Enter number of lines you'd like: ",10
        promptLen equ $-prompt ;; This returns the length of the string

section .bss
        linebuffer  resb 100

section .text
        global _start
_start:
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx, prompt
        mov edx, promptLen
        int 80h     ; sys_write(STD_OUT, prompt, promptLen)
        mov eax,3
        xor ebx,ebx
        mov ecx,linebuffer  ; reusing future linebuffer also for user input
        mov edx,1
        int 80h     ; sys_read(STD_IN, linebuffer, 1)
        ; linebuffer now contains single ASCII character from user -> size
        movzx esi,byte [linebuffer]
        sub esi,'0' ; esi = size of pyramid
        ; init values for line-loop, first data-like things
        mov edi,linebuffer  ; address where next asterisk should be written
        mov edx,1   ; number of chars to be displayed (line size) (1 = new line)
        ; init fixed values for outputting lines through "int 80h"
        mov ebx,1   ; STD_OUT
        mov ecx,linebuffer  ; address of linebuffer
pyramid_loop:
        cmp edx,esi ; already big enough line printed?
        ja  pyramid_done
        ; prepare line buffer by adding another asterisk, and increment line size
        mov [edi],word `*\n`    ; does also add new <new line> char at end
        inc edi     ; update address to write next asterisk
        inc edx     ; increase size of current line (line size)
        ; display the prepared line buffer
        mov eax,4   ; sys_write (has to be set again, sys_write return value modifies it)
        int 80h     ; sys_write(STD_OUT, linebuffer, "line size")
        jmp pyramid_loop
pyramid_done:
        mov eax,1   ; system call to exit
        xor ebx,ebx ; 0 exit code
        int 80h
```

It's 32 bit x86 assembly, to compile + run, save it into `ppp.asm`:

```
nasm -f elf ppp.asm; ld -m elf_i386 -s -o ppp ppp.o; ppp
```

I left there some comments about particular instructions, but you should be able to decipher the principle how it works on your own, or by watching the memory content changing in the debugger during loops.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's very helpful :) The comments are a massive help too! For the future learners, remember that sometimes the single quote can be an error. There are differences between ` and '

Comment: @Hugo-DanielCastillo well, if you don't know about the backticks in nasm, then that constant can be written also as `word ('*' + 10*256)` (should be "logical", why these values), or `word ('*' + (10<<8))` or if you are not lazy to check ASCII table, then `word 0x0A2A`, or any other way how to define a numeric word value... as long as the result is `0x0A2A` (`2A` = asterisk, `0A` = new line)